# Why am I getting Error 415 Unsupported Media Type on Submit

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am building a Self Hosting Web API ... I am trying to POST a record to a datastructure LIST.

Here is the Markup and and Jquery

```
<div>
    Last Name:
    <input id="LName"type="text" /><br />
    First Name:
    <input id="FName" type="text"/><br />
    Gender:
    <input id="Gender" type="text" /><br />
    Favorite Color:
    <input id="FavColor" type="text" /><br />
    Date of Birth:
    <input id="Dob" type="text" /><br /><br />
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <br /><br />
</div>
<div>
    <u>Person Data</u>
    <ul id="persons" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uri = "http://localhost:8080/api/persons";
    $("#persons").hide();
    getUsers();

    function getUsers() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON(uri)
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#persons").html("");
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    $("<li>", { html: item.lastName + " : " + item.firstName }).appendTo("#persons");
                });
            });
        });
    }

    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var Person = {
            LastName: $("#LName").val(),
            FirstName: $("#FName").val(),
            Gender: $("#Gender").val(),
            FavoriteColor: $("#FavColor").val(),
            DateOfBirth: $("#Dob").val()
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            type: 'POST',
            ContextType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            Accept: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(Person),
            Success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                getUsers();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error in Operation");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my host method:

```
public class Person
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteColor { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class PersonsController : ApiController
{
    List<Person> persons = fillPersons();

    public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
    {
        return (persons);
    }

    public void Post([FromBody] Person value)
    {
        Person postPer = new Person();
        postPer.LastName = value.LastName;
        postPer.FirstName = value.FirstName;
        postPer.Gender = value.Gender;
        postPer.FavoriteColor = value.FavoriteColor;
        postPer.DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(value.DateOfBirth);
        persons.Add(postPer);        
    }
}
```

I need to understand how to correct this error. The Get is working fine, but the Post is not working.

Comment: ContextType => ContentType

Comment: Try `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: Worked Great!! Thank you